Update gpg-agent version past the most recent apt version
I built the latest gnupg from the source code, but when I try generating a GPG key using gpg, I get the following warning:
gpg: WARNING: server 'gpg-agent' is older than us (2.2.27 < 2.4.5)
gpg: Note: Outdated servers may lack important security fixes.
gpg: Note: Use the command "gpgconf --kill all" to restart them.

I tried doing what it says, but it says the same thing. I tried sudo apt install gpg-agent gnupg but I get this:
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1).
gpg-agent is already the newest version (2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1).

When I do gpg-agent --version it says that it is version 2.4.5, so I tried which gpg-agent and it says that it's at /usr/local/bin/gpg-agent, but doing ps, it says that /usr/bin/gpg-agent is running. I tried manually killing it and running the one in /usr/local/bin instead, but looking at the process it is still running /usr/bin/gpg-agent. I tried removing gnupg and gpg-agent, but I get this error
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pop-default-settings : Depends: gnupg but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: python3-repolib (> 1.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
 pop-server : Depends: libblockdev-crypto2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

And after looking around I have been unable to find any way to change which agent it uses, or to update the one in /usr/bin.

Are you trying to update past the latest available, or are you trying to activate a new version that is already installed?

You have not provided enough information to diagnose if you actually do have the current version or your system simply is unaware of an update, since you have specified anything about the OS configuration

I built the latest gnupg from the source code, which is located in /usr/local/bin/ but I can't change the version of gpg-agent that is being ran to the later version, which is also installed in /usr/local/bin/, I am fine with either changing the version of gpg-agent that's being run to the already installed later version, or updating the existing version in /usr/bin/.

@sheep44 - Your question doesn’t mention that fact.

@Ramhound I didn't think it would be relevant information since I mention that I have both versions installed in those two different locations, but I added it to the question.
